# Infinite loop using iter method

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop

I am an amateur and am playing around with writing my own (very bad) compression tool, just for fun. 
The following code is used to read a text file and create a dictionary of the indexes of every character in the file. 
I'm trying to read the file in 1K chuncks, just for the hell of it but for some reason I get an infinite loop. 
I'm guessing I've misunderstood something in the "Iter" method.

code:

```
def dictify(myFile):
    compDict = {}
    count = 0
    with open(myFile, 'r') as f:
        for chunk in iter(f.read, 1024):
            for ch in chunk:
                if ch in compDict:
                    compDict[ch].append(count)
                else:
                    compDict[ch] = []
                    compDict[ch].append(count)
                count += 1
            print(compDict)
    print(compDict)

dictify('test.txt')
```

the print statement was for debugging purposes and I left it in because it will make it clear to whomever runs the code where the inf. loop is. 
Also - the txt file can be anything. Mine just says "I am the walrus"

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not how [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) works.

your example is given in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) as:

```
from functools import partial

with open('mydata.db', 'rb') as f:
    for block in iter(partial(f.read, 64), b''):
        process_block(block)
```

if you use `iter` with 2 arguments, the first must be a callable and the second a *sentinel*; i.e. something to look for when `iter` needs to terminate.

in your case the second argument is an integer (`1024`); `f.read` returns a string; so it will never terminate.

if you read your file in text mode (as opposed to binary) you need to make the following changes (i also adapted your block size):

```
with open('mydata.db', 'r') as f:
    for block in iter(partial(f.read, 1024), ''):
        process_block(block)
```

Comment: if you have text in your file read it as text by all means! the example in the doc was just for the binary case.

Comment: Thank you so much!